# Clean error handling approach in C

Tags: c, error-handling

I'm writing a C program that needs good error handling. The code likes like this:

```
If(doWork("A")<0){
    return -1;   
}
If(doWork("B")<0){
    undoWork("A");
    return -1;
}
If(doWork("C")<0){
    undoWork("A");
    undoWork("B");
    return -1;
}
return 0;
```

This code works but looks very messy, especially I have a long list of `doWork(X)` to call. Is there a better and cleaner approach to handle error in this case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid long chain of free's (or deletes) after every error check in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339946/how-to-avoid-long-chain-of-frees-or-deletes-after-every-error-check-in-c)

Comment: There are many good answers, but the best I can offer is a comment to go with them: whatever approach you take, you'll always minimize ugliness like this, and maximize robustness, by minimizing the number of steps that have a failure case. For example, precomputing the amount of memory you'll need and performing a single `malloc` before you get started instead of allocating small amounts at each step can make many tasks with complex error-out logic simple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some people, especially beginner-to-intermediate programmers, have a very idiosyncratic reaction to seeing `goto` in production code, but the usual idiom for sequential acquiring of resources and their intelligent release upon error is the following:

```
if(doWork("A") < 0)
  goto errA;

if(doWork("B") < 0)
  goto errB;

if(doWork("C") < 0)
  goto errC;

/* success! */
return 0;

/* Error handling / releasing resources section */
errC:
  undoWork("B");
errB:
  undoWork("A");
errA:

return -1;
```

You will see plenty of examples in system code, e.g. in the linux kernel.

Answer (score 2):

Being the same task `doWork`, you can probably define a linked list or vector of `jobs` and pass that as a parameter to `doWork`, append the corresponding information to this list inside the function, and only call `undoWork` once:

```
If(doWork("A", &jobs)<0){
    return -1;   
}
If(doWork("B", &jobs)<0){
    undoWork(jobs);
    return -1;
}
If(doWork("C", &jobs)<0){
    undoWork(jobs);
    return -1;
}
return 0;
```

This way, your logic will not become overly complicated, no matter the combination of jobs to be undone.

The advantage, compared to @twain249's solution, is that the function decides whether a job is added to the list or not, so you've got a nice isolation, modularity.

You can of course combine some form of an interable data structure with this, to **further reduce the amount of repetitive code**:

```
for(i=0; i < jobdata.size; i++) {
    If(doWork(jobdata[i], &jobs)<0){
        undowork(jobs);
        return -1;   
    }
}
```

As you can notice, data structure design plays an important role in algorithm design, usually a much more important one than one usually thinks.

*There could be thousands of jobs, the code will remain a four-liner.*

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. Newer languages like C++ and C# favor exceptions to help improve situations just like this.

Perhaps you could have a table that somehow indicated which tasks you've done and undo those. But I really think that would make your code more complex and not less.

Also note that, while there are some pretty strong feelings about using `goto`, there are in fact times when that can simplify structures like this.

Comment: Even newer languages like golang have even better constructs like `defer`.

Answer (score 0):

if it's possible to store all things you have to call `doWork` on in an array then you could shorten the code significantly something like.

```
int i = 0;
int len = MAX_NUM; //set to the value of calls
int error = 0;

for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if(doWork(a[i]) < 0) {
        error = 1;
        break;
    }
}

if(error) {
    for(int j = 0; j < i; i++) {
        undoWork(a[j]);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a super long list, you can approach it this way.

```
if (dowork("A") >=0) {
if (dowork("B") >=0) {
if (dowork("C") >=0) {
if (dowork("D") >=0) return 0;
undowork("C"); }
undowork("B"); }
undowork("A"); }
return -1;
```

Comment: I don't understand why people were down voting this. When compiled it will be exactly the same as doing the goto/label technique.

Answer (score 0):

There is also another widely used approach based on a single pass loop that is clear and doesn't require goto. It implies though that Undo functions correctly handle both work that was done and that was not.

```
do
{
  if(doWork("A")<0)
    break;   

  if(doWork("B")<0)
    break;

  if(doWork("C")<0)
    break;

  return 0;
}
while(0);

undoWork("A");
undoWork("B");
undoWork("C");
return -1;
```