# Moving from C++ to C

Tags: c++, c

After a few years coding in C++, I was recently offered a job coding in C, in the embedded field.

Putting aside the question of whether it's right or wrong to dismiss C++ in the embedded field, there are some features/idioms in C++ I would miss a lot. Just to name a few:

- Generic, type-safe data structures (using templates).
- RAII. Especially in functions with multiple return points, e.g. not having to remember to release the mutex on each return point.
- Destructors in general. I.e. you write a d'tor once for MyClass, then if a MyClass instance is a member of MyOtherClass, MyOtherClass doesn't have to explicitly deinitialize the MyClass instance - its d'tor is called automatically.
- Namespaces.

What are your experiences moving from C++ to C?
What C substitutes did you find for your favorite C++ features/idioms? Did you discover any C features you wish C++ had?

Comment: Reposted on programmers.se, as suggested:  
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/15807/moving-from-c-to-c-your-experiences  
There really should be an option to move questions from SO to programmers.se, if only for this kind of too-subjective questions.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Working on an embedded project, I tried working in all C once, and just couldn't stand it.  It was just so verbose that it made it hard to read anything.  Also, I liked the optimized-for-embedded containers I had written, which had to turn into much less safe and harder to fix `#define` blocks.

Code that in C++ looked like:

```
if(uart[0]->Send(pktQueue.Top(), sizeof(Packet)))
    pktQueue.Dequeue(1);
```

turns into:

```
if(UART_uchar_SendBlock(uart[0], Queue_Packet_Top(pktQueue), sizeof(Packet)))
    Queue_Packet_Dequeue(pktQueue, 1);
```

which many people will probably say is fine but gets ridiculous if you have to do more than a couple "method" calls in a line.  Two lines of C++ would turn into five of C (due to 80-char line length limits).  Both would generate the same code, so it's not like the target processor cared!

One time (back in 1995), I tried writing a lot of C for a multiprocessor data-processing program.  The kind where each processor has its own memory and program.  The vendor-supplied compiler was a C compiler (some kind of HighC derivative), their libraries were closed source so I couldn't use GCC to build, and their APIs were designed with the mindset that your programs would primarily be the initialize/process/terminate variety, so inter-processor communication was rudimentary at best.

I got about a month in before I gave up, found a copy of [cfront](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cfront), and hacked it into the makefiles so I could use C++.  Cfront didn't even support templates, but the C++ code was much, much clearer.

### Generic, type-safe data structures (using templates).

The closest thing C has to templates is to declare a header file with a lot of code that looks like:

```
TYPE * Queue_##TYPE##_Top(Queue_##TYPE##* const this)
{ /* ... */ }
```

then pull it in with something like:

```
#define TYPE Packet
#include "Queue.h"
#undef TYPE
```

Note that this won't work for compound types (e.g. no queues of `unsigned char`) unless you make a `typedef` first.

Oh, and remember, if this code isn't actually used anywhere, then you don't even know if it's syntactically correct.

**EDIT:** One more thing: you'll need to *manually* manage instantiation of code.  If your "template" code isn't *all* inline functions, then you'll have to put in some control to make sure that things get instantiated only once so your linker doesn't spit out a pile of "multiple instances of Foo" errors.

To do this, you'll have to put the non-inlined stuff in an "implementation" section in your header file:

```
#ifdef implementation_##TYPE

/* Non-inlines, "static members", global definitions, etc. go here. */

#endif
```

And then, in *one* place in all your code *per template variant*, you have to:

```
#define TYPE Packet
#define implementation_Packet
#include "Queue.h"
#undef TYPE
```

Also, this implementation section needs to be *outside* the standard `#ifndef`/`#define`/`#endif` litany, because you may include the template header file in another header file, but need to instantiate afterward in a `.c` file.

Yep, it gets ugly fast.  Which is why most C programmers don't even try.

### RAII.

Especially in functions with multiple return points, e.g. not having to remember to release the mutex on each return point.

Well, forget your pretty code and get used to all your return points (except the end of the function) [being `goto`s:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788903/valid-use-of-goto-for-error-management-in-c)

```
TYPE * Queue_##TYPE##_Top(Queue_##TYPE##* const this)
{
    TYPE * result;
    Mutex_Lock(this->lock);
    if(this->head == this->tail)
    {
        result = 0;
        goto Queue_##TYPE##_Top_exit:;
    }

    /* Figure out `result` for real, then fall through to... */

Queue_##TYPE##_Top_exit:
    Mutex_Lock(this->lock);
    return result;
}
```

### Destructors in general.

I.e. you write a d'tor once for MyClass, then if a MyClass instance is a member of MyOtherClass, MyOtherClass doesn't have to explicitly deinitialize the MyClass instance - its d'tor is called automatically.

Object construction has to be explicitly handled the same way.

### Namespaces.

That's actually a simple one to fix: just tack a prefix onto *every* symbol.  This is the primary cause of the source bloat that I talked about earlier (since classes are implicit namespaces).  The C folks have been living this, well, forever, and probably won't see what the big deal is.

YMMV

Comment: Of course you hate C if you try to force it to be C++. I doubt C++ would look great if you tried to impose features from $more_expressive_language into it either. Not a critique to your post, just an observation :-)

Comment: Regarding the goto-instead-of-RAII technique: Isn't it a maintenance nightmare? i.e. whenever you add a code path that needs cleanup, or even just change the order of things inside the function, you have to remember to go to the goto labels at the end and change them as well. I'd like to see a technique that somehow registers the cleanup code right next to what needs to be cleaned up.

Comment: @george: I hate to say it, but most embedded C code I've seen is pretty bad by C standards. For example, I'm working with Atmel's at91lib right now, and it requires you to write a "board.h" file that the majority of their code pulls in as a dependency. (For their demo board, this header is 792 lines long.)  Also, a "LowLevelInit()" function that you have to customize for your board is almost entirely register accesses, with lines like `AT91C_BASE_PMC->PMC_MOR = (0x37 << 16) | BOARD_OSCOUNT | AT91C_CKGR_MOSCRCEN | AT91C_CKGR_MOSCXTEN | AT91C_CKGR_MOSCSEL;`

Comment: Oh, and nothing there tells you that `BOARD_OSCOUNT` (which is the value of the timeout for waiting for a clock to switch; clear, huh?) is actually a `#define` in `board.h`. There is also, in that same function, a lot of copy-and-pasted spin loop code, which should have been turned into a two-line `#define` (and, when I did just that, it saved a few bytes of code and made the function more readable by making register sets and spin loops more distinct).  One of the big reasons to use C is that it lets you micromanage and optimize everything, but most code I've seen doesn't bother.

Comment: @Mads: Please don't get me wrong. I don't hate C. I'm not a huge fan, granted, but I do acknowledge its strengths.  Historically, C has been more portable and standardized, and even now its standards have a lot of features I'd love to see in C++, like the ability to generate an array of static, global structs using non-default constructors. Serial ports are a good example; for a serial port class on a chip with 4 ports, I'd love to create an array of `SerialPort` objects, each with a different base address.  Then in some places I can loop through them as an array without extra init code.

Comment: Agree with @Mads.  No reason to go through all of that for features you don't really need.  I find I enjoy a style similar to the GTK library.  Define your "classes" as structs and then create consistent methods such as my_class_new() and then pass that into the "methods": my_class_do_this(my_class_instance)

Comment: I don't really care for the Gtk+ way, and yes, I've written Gtk+ code... and moved to gtkmm.  The problems I had with Gtk+ is how you have a macro for everything, which you need to remember, and if you use a normal typecast instead of Gtk+'s (say, to go from an object pointer to a pointer to its superclass form), it isn't caught as an error. Also, whenever I run a Gtk+ program from the command line, there's endless "Gtk+ WARNING" spam, even from included Gnome programs.  YMMV.

Comment: @Mark: You're actually making a different argument. @Mads said you're not going to like going from any more expressive language to a less expressive one. @Max advocated discarding the class management features of C++ and doing it all manually in C. Best I can tell, you're equating C++ usage with the Inner Platform effect. I can't agree with that premise. Your argument can be used to advocate developing in assembly instead of C, since every feature of C can be replicated in assembly. Also, I fail to see how (I guess) defining a few templates is "making **everything** generic". It's DRY.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone quick question about your answer (sorry, I know it's literally decades ago)... it seems to hint that ## can be used outside of the context of a #define ... is that true??? When I try a simple c example on gcc it complains about a "stray # in code". Secondly, I thought in C you could not `#define TYPE Packet` unless `Packet` itself is defined as a constant expression beforehand. Is this valid c? Or is it code that needs to be specifically compiled via g++?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou If ## were to parse outside a #define, I'm not sure there is any point to using it. It exists to say "join the literals on either side, after substitutions, into a single literal." Outside of a #define, there's no substitution being performed, so why not drop the ## and join the two halves right there in the source?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou As to your second question, '#define A B C D ...' originally meant "replace the identifier A with the literal characters B C D ... when you see it." Later, "literal characters" became "tokens," but it's still pretty much the same. In any case, there's no knowledge of the meaning of B C D ... until later, when the preprocessed file is compiled. Remember, originally all # commands were handled by the preprocessor, an entirely separate program that does not know C's syntax. It output a single file which was then fed to the C compiler, which never saw an # command.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone Thanks. I wasn't sure if you were doing something weird and esoteric that I'd never seen before, or had simply omitted the implied `#define`s for stylistic reasons :)

Answer (score 18):

I moved from C++ to C for a different reason (some sort of allergic reaction ;) and there are only a few thing that I miss and some things that I gained. If you stick to C99, if you may, there are constructs that let you program quite nicely and safely, in particular

- designated initializers (eventually
  combined with macros) make
  initialization of simple classes as
  painless as constructors
- compound literals for temporary variables
- `for`-scope variable may help you to do [scope bound resource management](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/group__preprocessor__blocks.html), in particular to ensure to `unlock` of mutexes or `free` of arrays, even under preliminary function returns
- `__VA_ARGS__` macros can be used to have default arguments to functions and to do code unrolling
- `inline` functions and macros that combine well to replace (sort of) overloaded functions

Comment: @Mike: for which part in particular? If you follow the link I gave for the `for` scopes, you'll land on P99, where you may look around also for examples and descriptions of the other parts.

Comment: @Mike: [There you go.](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/utilities.html#blocks)

Comment: @george: Thanks!  @Jens: Examples of the the other four.  I've fallen behind on my C; last I heard they added runtime-sized automatic-allocated (i.e. stack) arrays (e.g. `void DoSomething(unsigned char* buf, size_t bufSize) { unsigned char temp[bufSize]; ... }`) and structure initialization by field names (e.g. `struct Foo bar = { .field1 = 5, .field2 = 10 };`), the latter which I'd love to see in C++, especially with non-POD objects (e.g. `UART uart[2] = { UART(0x378), UART(0x278) };`).

Comment: @Mike: yes there are variable length arrays (VLA), but they may be a bit dangerous to use because of potential stackoverflow. The second that you describe are exactly the "designated initializer", so there you go with your own example ;-) For the others you find info on the P99 link above if you click on "related Pages".

Answer (score 9):

The difference between C and C++ is the predictability of the code's behavior.

It is a easier to predict with great accuracy what your code will do in C, in C++ it might become a bit more difficult to come up with an exact prediction.

The predictability in C gives you better control of what your code is doing, but that also means you have to do more stuff.

In C++ you can write less code to get the same thing done, but (at leas for me) I have trouble occasionally knowing how the object code is laid out in memory and it's expected behavior.

Comment: Whenever I worry about what the code is really doing, I add the `-s` flag to `gcc` to get the assembly dump, search for the function of concern, and start reading.  It's a great way to learn any compiled language's quirks.

Comment: It's also a waste of time, seeing as C++ generated assembly would be like reading Perl. Bravo for looking anyway.

Answer (score 8):

Nothing like the STL exists for C.
There are libs available which provide similar functionality, but it isn't builtin anymore.

Think that would be one of my biggest problems... Knowing with which tool I could solve the problem, but not having the tools available in the language I have to use.

Comment: this is true.could anyone elaborate on which container-class libraries should one use for C ? Or is the answer "write one yourself " ?

Comment: @Sandeep: For starters, this answer is only right about containers not being in the standard lib. Apart from lacking an STL equivalent (the best part of C++), the C standard library is far superior. POSIX contains tsearch, lsearch, hsearch, and bsearch in addition to qsort which is in libc. Glib is the definitive "Boost" of C, take a look it's packed with goodies (containers included). http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/. Glib also integrates with Gtk+, a combination which exceeds Boost and Qt. There is also libapr, popular for xplatform stuff like Subversion and Apache.

Comment: I can't find any libs of c which could compete with the stl, they are harder to use, more difficult to maintain, the performance are not the rival of stl when they want to keep the c libs as generic as stl.This is the limitation of c, and the reasons why we can't have something like stl in c library, because c simply don't have the ability to develop something like stl.

Answer (score 7):

In my line of work - which is embedded, by the way - I am constantly switching back & forth between C and C++.

When I'm in C, I miss from C++:

- templates (including but not limited to STL containers).  I use them for things like special counters, buffer pools, etc. (built up my own library of class templates & function templates that I use in different embedded projects)
- very powerful standard library
- destructors, which of course make RAII possible (mutexes, interrupt disable, tracing, etc.)
- access specifiers, to better enforce who can use (not see) what

I use inheritance on larger projects, and C++'s built-in support for it is much cleaner & nicer than the C "hack" of embedding the base class as the first member (not to mention automatic invocation of constructors, init. lists, etc.) but the items listed above are the ones I miss the most.

Also, probably only about a third of the embedded C++ projects I work on use exceptions, so I've become accustomed to living without them, so I don't miss them too much when I move back to C.

On the flip side, when I move back to a C project with a significant number of developers, there are whole classes of C++ problems that I'm used to explaining to people which go away.  Mostly problems due to the complexity of C++, and people who think they know what's going on, but they're really at the "C with classes" part of the [**C++ confidence curve**](http://lbrandy.com/blog/2010/03/never-trust-a-programmer-who-says-he-knows-c/).

Given the choice, I'd prefer using C++ on a project, but only if the team is pretty solid on the language.  Also of course assuming it's not an 8K μC project where I'm effectively writing "C" anyway.

Comment: That "C++ Confidence Curve" bothers me a bit.  The way it's written, and the comments, implies that C++ is hopeless, a lost cause, or whatever.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Take the plunge, we'll see you in a few years. Most good programmers come out the other side with a sour taste.

Answer (score 3):

Couple of observations

- Unless you plan to use your c++ compiler to build your C (which is possible if you stick to a well define subset of C++) you will soon discover things that your compiler allows in C that would be a compile error in C++.
- No more cryptic template errors (yay!)
- No (language supported) object oriented programming

Comment: C do not support template do not mean we don't need "generic paradigms", in C you have to use void* and macro to mimic template if you need "generic paradigms".void* is not type safe, the errors of macro also pretty crappy, not better than template.Template is much more easier to read and maintain than macro, plus type safe.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much the same reasons I have for using C++ or a mix of C/C++ rather than pure C. I can live without namespaces but I use them all the time if the code standard allows it. The reasons is that you can write much more compact code in C++. This is very usefull for me, I write servers in C++ which tend to crash now and then. At that point it helps a lot if the code you are looking at is short and consist. For example consider the following code:

```
uint32_t 
ScoreList::FindHighScore(
  uint32_t p_PlayerId)
{
  MutexLock lock(m_Lock); 

  uint32_t highScore = 0; 
  for(int i = 0; i < m_Players.Size(); i++)
  {
    Player& player = m_Players[i]; 
    if(player.m_Score > highScore)
      highScore = player.m_Score; 
  }

  return highScore; 
}
```

In C that looks like:

```
uint32_t 
ScoreList_getHighScore(
  ScoreList* p_ScoreList)
{
  uint32_t highScore = 0; 

  Mutex_Lock(p_ScoreList->m_Lock); 

  for(int i = 0; i < Array_GetSize(p_ScoreList->m_Players); i++)
  {
    Player* player = p_ScoreList->m_Players[i]; 
    if(player->m_Score > highScore)
      highScore = player->m_Score; 
  }

  Mutex_UnLock(p_ScoreList->m_Lock);

  return highScore; 
}
```

Not a world of difference. One more line of code, but that tends to add up. Nomally you try your best to keep it clean and lean but sometimes you have to do something more complex. And in those situations you value your line count. One more line is one more thing to look at when you try to figure out why your broadcast network suddenly stops delivering messages.

Anyway I find that C++ allows me to do more complex things in a safe fashion.

Comment: In C you cannot do this  "for(int i = 0".

Comment: Victor it is valid c99 though(or compiling c with a c++ compiler for some typing issue).

Comment: I find I cannot trust the safety. So your mutex is scoped. Now you don't know why its being unlocked should an exception "wander" through. You don't even know when it will be unlocked, any part of your code might decide its had enough and throw. Those extra implicit "safeties" may be masking bugs.

Comment: Matt, we do know why it unlocked.In normal case, when the program reach the end of the scope, the mutex will unlock, we don't need to unlock it by hand made codes, it is a maintenance nightmare.If there are exception occur, the mutex will be unlocked, and we could catch the exception and read the error message from it.The error message is good enough or not will depend on how do you play with the exception.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem why c++ is harder to be accepted in embedded environment is because of the lack of engineers that understand how to use c++ properly.

Yes, the same reasoning can be applied to C as well, but luckily there aren't that many pitfalls in C that can shoot yourself in the foot. C++ on the other hand, you need to know when not to use certain features in c++.

All in all, I like c++. I use that on the O/S services layer, driver, management code, etc.
But if your team doesn't have enough experience with it, it's gonna be a tough challenge.

I had experience with both. When the rest of the team wasn't ready for it, it was a total disaster. On the other hand, it was good experience.

Answer (score 1):

yes! i have experienced both of these languages and what i found is C++ is more friendly language. It facilitates with more features. It is better to say that C++ is superset of C language as it provide additional features like polymorphism, interitance, operator and function overloading, user defined data types which is not really supported in C. The thousand lines of code is reduce to few lines with the help of object oriented programming that's the main reason of moving from C to C++.

Comment: @exnihilo The convention superset here is to define that C++ comes with more features. It also improves the syntax and semantic and reduce error chances. There are some code which did not compile in C++ but can in C, like  const int a; This will gives an error in C++ as it is necessary to initialize a constant at time of declaration while in C the concept will compile. So superset is not a hard and fast rule like in mathematics(A⊂B) rather it is an approximation that C++ provides  additional features like object oriented concept.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, the desire to escape complex/messy syntax is understandable. Sometimes C can appear to be the solution. However, C++ is where the industry support is, including tooling and libraries, so that is hard to work around.

C++ has so many features today including lambdas.

A good approach is to leverage C++ itself to make your code simpler. Objects are good for isolating things under the hood so that at a higher level, the code is simpler. The core guidelines recommend concrete (simple) objects, so that approach can help.

The level of complexity is under the engineer's control. If multiple inheritance (MI) is useful in a scenario and one prefers that option, then one may use MI.

Alternatively, one can define interfaces, inherit from the interface(s), and contain implementing objects (composition/aggregation) and expose the objects through the interface using inline wrappers. The inline wrappers compile down to nothing, i.e., compile down to simple use of the internal (contained) object, yet the container object appears to have that functionality as if multiple inheritance was used.

C++ also has namespaces, so one should leverage namespaces even if coding in a C-like style.

One can use the language itself to create simpler patterns and the STL is full of examples: array, vector, map, queue, string, unique_ptr,... And one can control (to a reasonable extent) how complex their code is.

So, going back to C is not the way, nor is it necessary. One may use C++ in a C-like way, or use C++ multiple inheritance, or use any option in-between.