# use of GOTO & Labels in SQL inside SQL Transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a long running script that I want to wrap in transactions which could have up to **100+ transactions** in it.

I would like to implement some error handling and re-use of code.  I was thinking of using a label and GOTO statements.

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION abc
    --DO SOMETHING
    COMMIT TRANSACTION abc;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    GOTO ERROR_OUT
END CATCH

ERROR_OUT:  
       SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() [ErrorMessage];  
       ROLLBACK;
```

**Is this something that should be done while using many transactions?**

In my simple tests where I forced an error I noticed that the ERROR_MESSGE() SELECT statement did not return results.

**Is there a way to get that to select statement to return results when using a label?**

Comment: I would run away from using GOTO as fast as possible. It creates code that is incredibly painful to maintain. Especially with 100+ such transaction think about spaghetti like this code will be. I would argue that your script is already way too long for reasonable maintenance.

Comment: @SeanLange Agreed however, this is a one time script and I really want decent error messages on the parts that fail.

Comment: Combine checking for @@ERROR and Throwing Custom Exceptions. You can get a nice error out and rollback your tx without using a label.

Comment: have you tried assigning it to a variable inside your catch?

Comment: @RossBush - Can you provide a simple example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, programmers are discouraged from using `goto`. The reason is that it is a control-flow primitive, and alternatives exist for many commonly used cases: `if`/then/`else`, `while`, and so on.

However, there are circumstances where `goto` is quite useful. And error handling is one of them. If you google "goto error handling", it is not hard to find explanations such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788903/valid-use-of-goto-for-error-management-in-c), or [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/154974/is-this-a-decent-use-case-for-goto-in-c) (although for C, I think the reasoning is very similar).

I have often used `goto` in SQL Server stored procedures for exactly this purpose. Although in my case, the goal was to achieve proper auditing and error processing when leaving the stored procedure.

Your use-case would seem to be a fine example where `goto` is a very reasonable way to code the block. I do find the "hundreds of transactions" part more questionable. Personally, I like to be explicit about when and where transactions are processed, so I would be more likely to write:

```
. . .
begin catch:
    rollback ;
    goto error_out;
end;
```

That is, to explicitly rollback the transaction "next to" where the transaction begins, rather than doing that in some far-away code block.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer.  I'm not sure how else I could do my long running script as I will have to hand this off to someone else in the production environment.  But that might be another question.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

```
Declare @Table table (Num float,Den float,Pct float)
Insert into @Table values (25,100,0),(50,0,0)

BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION abc
    -- Force a Divide by Zero on 2nd record
    Update @Table Set Pct=Num/Den
    COMMIT TRANSACTION abc;
    Select * from @Table
    GOTO CLEAN_OUT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    Declare @Error varchar(max)=Error_Message()
    GOTO ERROR_OUT
END CATCH

ERROR_OUT: 
    ROLLBACK;
    Select ErrorMessage=@Error 
    Select * From @Table

CLEAN_OUT:
Go
```

Returns

```
ErrorMessage
Divide by zero error encountered.

Num Den Pct
25  100 0
50  0   0
```

And then try it with (50,125,0)

Comment: Thanks, I tested this out and it works.  I will be implementing part of your answer to my code in the future.