Best/Cleanest way to structure error checking on dynamically allocated variables
I am working on a Python C project that involves a couple of dynamically allocated structures like queues and threading structures. I am mainly looking to improve the readability. It looks something like this:
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Queue{
   void *data;
} Queue;
typedef struct Control{
   void *data;
} Control;
typedef struct Logging{
   void *data;
} Logging;
typedef struct Args{
   Queue *q;
   Control *c;
   Logging *l;
   void *data;
} Args;

void cleanupQueue(Queue *q);
void cleanupControl(Control *c);
void cleanupLogging(Logging *l);
void cleanupArgs(Args *a);
static PyObject *pycalledfunction(){
  Queue *queue = (Queue *) malloc(sizeof(Queue));
  if(!queue){
    PyErr_SetString(type, message);
    return NULL;
  }
  // initialize queue and fill
  
  Control *control = (Control *) malloc(sizeof(Control));
  if(!control){
    cleanupQueue(queue);
    PyErr_SetString(type, message);
    return NULL;
  }
  // initialize control
  
  Logging *logging = (Logging *) malloc(sizeof(Logging));
  if(!logging){
    cleanupControl(control);
    cleanupQueue(queue);
    PyErr_SetString(type, message);
    return NULL;
  }
  // initialize logging
  
  Args *args = (Args *) malloc(sizeof(Args));
  if(!logging){
    cleanupLogging(logging);
    cleanupControl(control);
    cleanupQueue(queue);
    PyErr_SetString(type, message);
    return NULL;
  }
  // initialize and fill args with the other structs
  
  // Note: I guess I could check if they all exist before doing work with them here but I was unsure if that is a good practice since I am loading them into the args and am keen on getting the correct error message.
  
  // bunch of work here
  
  cleanupQueue(queue);
  cleanupControl(control);
  cleanupLogging(logging);
  cleanupArgs(args);
  return obj;
}

Now this code works just fine as long as it cleans up the allocated memory properly; although it lowers the flow of the code and its overall readability by a small margin, I am still looking to improve my structuring practices by any margin. I left a note in there marking that I could check each of the structures before doing any work(having all of the checking in the same place), but I feel as if this would result in the same flow.
Is there any way to do this in a way that ensures that I return the correct error while improving the structure of my code?
EDIT: Decided that goto statements are sufficient enough to clean the code enough(while maintaining good practice). If there are any other methods that you believe clean the code further, send me a message to reopen.
EDIT: Note of semi-duplicate to this question

Consider code review for working code.

Reduce wet C code: Queue *queue = (Queue *) malloc(sizeof(Queue)); --> Queue *queue = malloc(sizeof *queue);

@chux-ReinstateMonica okay i will close this and reopen in working.

typedef struct Queue; ==> Um, where's the alias?

Why is this C function named main()? Or alternatively, why is it returning a PyObject *?  These do not go together.  Is this supposed to be part of a native Python extension, or is it supposed to be a C program with an embedded Python interpreter?

@JohnBollinger You're right, I was quickly typing up the example and originally had it as int main(){ changed it to PyObject * to reflect that it is a Python-called function but forgot to change the name.

@Harith You're right, I forgot to add them when typing up the example. I had them at the top just to show readers that they were existing structures.

You can pull out good ol' goto (this is one valid use-case of goto):
static PyObject *pycalledfunction()
{
  Queue *queue = malloc(sizeof *queue);

  if (!queue){
      goto fail_queue;
  }
  
  Control *control = malloc(sizeof *control);

  if (!control){
      goto fail_control;
  }
  
  Logging *logging = malloc(sizeof *logging);

  if (!logging){
      goto fail_logging;
  }
  
  Args *args = malloc(sizeof *args);

  if (!args){
      goto fail_args;
  }

  cleanupQueue(queue);
  cleanupControl(control);
  cleanupLogging(logging);
  cleanupArgs(args);
  return obj;
  
fail_args:
  cleanupLogging(logging);
fail_logging:
    cleanupControl(control);
fail_control:
    cleanupQueue(queue);
fail_queue:
    PyErr_SetString(type, message);
    return NULL;
}

My labels may not be creative enough, rename them however you may. Or use the nested approach that @Jonathan Leffer shows here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788903/valid-use-of-goto-for-error-management-in-c.

Tempted to mark this as the solution. I had looked at goto a little bit but mostly passed it by unsure if it would make it more unreadable(and a good practice). Will the code within the goto labels fail_args: run at the end of the function or are they unreachable if that return obj; was not there above it?

@BaccaRulerMC They can only be reached by a goto since return obj; will make the program return from the function if it's reached.

@TedLyngmo Okay, so it will reach the code if not returned beforehand. Thanks.

As I understand the question, it is about how on passing each point of possible allocation failure, you accumulate one more cleanup function to call.  You end up with multiple, partially-duplicate lists of cleanup calls.
One way to approach this issue would be by nesting, so that the cleanup logic flows naturally:
  PyObject *rval = NULL;

  Queue *queue = malloc(sizeof(*queue));
  if(!queue){
    PyErr_SetString(type, message);
  } else {
    // initialize queue and fill
  
    Control *control = malloc(sizeof(*control));
    if(!control){
      PyErr_SetString(type2, message2);
    } else {
      // initialize control
  
      Logging *logging = malloc(sizeof(*logging));
      if(!logging) {
        PyErr_SetString(type3, message3);
      } else {
        // initialize logging
  
        Args *args = malloc(sizeof(*args));
        if(!args) {
          PyErr_SetString(type4, message4);
        } else {
          // initialize and fill args with the other structs
  
          // ... bunch of work here ...

          rval = obj;

          cleanupArgs(args);
        }
        cleanupLogging(logging);
      }
      cleanupControl(control);
    }
    cleanupQueue(queue);
  }
  return rval;

You could also do similar by putting each of those nested blocks into its own function, each one calling the next until you ultimately get to the one doing the actual work.  That might be more satisfactory to some programmers' sensibilities.
And you could do similar with goto, as your other answer suggests.  I consider that a reasonable and legitimate use of goto, and I have personally written similar error-handling code using goto.  However, as a personal preference, I do prefer to reserve goto for cases that cannot readily be handled another way.  As you depict it, this is not such a case.

Thanks for the insight. I have been avoiding nested-ifs even though it may be the least wet solution. This is only because the work already contains nested-ifs to ensure that the control thread, parse thread are valid before looping the creation of worker threads. In that case, the processing would happen 7 nested levels. While I can even read the current implementation, I aim to make sure everyone has an easy time following the code.

Based on the answers from @Harith and @John Bollinger (as well as the comment from @Ted Lyngmo), combining the two approaches to structure [nested-ifs, goto] may output the cleanest structure.
Using the example:
static PyObject *pycalledfunction()
{
  PyObject *error_typ = NULL;
  PyObject *rval = NULL;
  char *error_msg = NULL;
  Queue *queue = malloc(sizeof *queue);
  if (!queue){
      error_typ = PyExc_RuntimeError; // insert proper error type here
      error_msg = "failed to allocate Queue";
      goto fail_queue;
  }
  
  Control *control = malloc(sizeof *control);
  if (!control){
      error_typ = PyExc_RuntimeError; // insert proper error type here
      error_msg = "failed to allocate Control";
      goto fail_control;
  }
  
  Logging *logging = malloc(sizeof *logging);
  if (!logging){
      error_typ = PyExc_RuntimeError; // insert proper error type here
      error_msg = "failed to allocate Logging";
      goto fail_logging;
  }
  
  Args *args = malloc(sizeof *args);
  if (!args){
      error_typ = PyExc_RuntimeError; // insert proper error type here
      error_msg = "failed to allocate Args";
      goto fail_args;
  }
fail_args:
   cleanupArgs(args);
fail_logging:
   cleanupLogging(logging);
fail_control:
   cleanupControl(control);
fail_queue:
   cleanupQueue(queue);
  
  if(error_typ || error_msg){
     PyErr_SetString(type, message);
     return NULL;
  }

  return rval;
}

This approach allows the reduction of wet code that the nested-ifs and the simplicity of the goto statements. To reduce the lines of code in the checking, another structure could be implemented(although almost unnecessary):
typedef struct MyPyError {
   PyObject type;
   char *msg;
} MyPyError;

static PyObject *pycalledfunction()
{
   MyPyError error;

   // ...
   if(!queue){
      error = (MyPyError) {PyExc_RuntimeError, "failed to allocate queue"};
      goto fail_queue;
   }
   // ...
   if(error){
      PyErr_SetString(error.type, error.msg);
      return NULL;
   }
   return rval;
}
   

